# Связка ReactJS + PHP

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, reactjs, webpack

Появилась задача написать небольшой сайт на **Реакте (SPA)**, где в роли бэкэнда будет выступать **WordPress** (при желании можно его заменить на обычный **php**). Собственно на предыдущих проектах работал только с связке Реакт + нода и понятия не имею как "скрестить" php с Реактом, а точнее с Вебпаком  у которого в качестве входных параметров идет JS файл в который подтягиваются остальные компонетнты... Но как в данный проект подтянуть php код?? Нужна хотя бы просто логика/идея как это реализовать, ну или пример с гитхаба...

Comment: Читайте статьи на тему JAM Stack на Wordpress

Comment: Делайте обычный Restful API на php. Потом отдельно frontend часть на React.

Comment: @Krya спс большое, очень помогло!